# django does not render after POST request

Tags: javascript, django, rendering

I have a js code, which on the on click event sends a POST request to /productionFloor/wip/
I have a view that receives those requests (also printing to the console all the arguments that were passed correctly).
I'm trying to render a template with the data received from the POST request, but django won't render the view.

Here is my view:

```
def wip_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.POST['id'])
    print(request.POST['process'])
return render(request, 'wip.html', {'nbar': 'production_floor'})
```

Here is the js:

```
        $(".clickable-schedule-row").dblclick(function() {
        id=$(this).children('td')[6].innerHTML;
        process=$(this).children('td')[7].innerHTML;
                    $.post("/productionFloor/wip/", {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                            'id': id, 'process': process});
    });
```

as I mentioned, the server gets the request correctly and prints the right data, but it won't change the page on the browser.

Comment: you are making an ajax request so $.post will have a callback function which will return you the rendered view. you need to add that view to your html page

Comment: add console.log() in your js code after the post request.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are using the ajax call from jQuery. Django return the response in json/string format. Inside the success method you will have to make changes to reflect it in the HTML pages.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/productionFloor/wip/',
      data:"{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                        'id': id, 'process': process}",
      success: function(response) {
         // inside this function you have to bind html content using javascript, because ajax call will not render complete page.
    });
```